# Second Activity doesnt start , App force closes : Fatal exception main ; java.lang.ClassCastException:android.app.Application

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am trying to make an app which gives the list of installed apps and when an item is clicked , starts another activity which states the permissions required by installed apps. I got the installed application list, but when I click any app instead of starting new activity , the application force closes.

MainActivity

```
package com.example.appslist;

import java.util.List;
import com.example.appslist.adapter.ApkAdapter;
import com.example.appslist.app.AppData;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class ApkListActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    PackageManager packageManager;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        packageManager = getPackageManager();
        List<PackageInfo> packageList = packageManager
                .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

        ListView mylistview= (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        mylistview.setAdapter(new ApkAdapter(this, packageList, packageManager));
        mylistview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long row) {

        PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) parent
                .getItemAtPosition(position);
        AppData appData = (AppData) getApplication();
        appData.setPackageInfo(packageInfo);

        Intent appInfo = new Intent(ApkListActivity.this, ApkInfo.class);
        startActivity(appInfo);
    }
}
```

ApkInfo.java

```
package com.example.appslist;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import com.example.appslist.app.AppData;
import android.content.pm.FeatureInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ApkInfo extends Activity {

  TextView appLabel, packageName, version, features;
    TextView permissions, andVersion,path;
    PackageInfo packageInfo;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.apkinfo);

        findViewsById();

        AppData appData = (AppData) getApplicationContext();
        packageInfo = appData.getPackageInfo();

        setValues();

    }

    private void findViewsById() {
        appLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.applabel);
        packageName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.package_name);
        version = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.version_name);
        features = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.req_feature);
        permissions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.req_permission);
        andVersion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.andversion);
        path = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.path);

    }

    private void setValues() {
        // APP name
        appLabel.setText(getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(
                packageInfo.applicationInfo));

        // package name
        packageName.setText(packageInfo.packageName);

        // version name
        version.setText(packageInfo.versionName);

        // target version
        andVersion.setText(Integer
                .toString(packageInfo.applicationInfo.targetSdkVersion));

        // path
        path.setText(packageInfo.applicationInfo.sourceDir);


        // features
        if (packageInfo.reqFeatures != null)
            features.setText(getFeatures(packageInfo.reqFeatures));
        else
            features.setText("-");

        // uses-permission
        if (packageInfo.requestedPermissions != null)
            permissions
                    .setText(getPermissions(packageInfo.requestedPermissions));
        else
            permissions.setText("-");
    }

    // Convert string array to comma separated string
    private String getPermissions(String[] requestedPermissions) {
        String permission = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
            permission = permission + requestedPermissions[i] + ",\n";
        }
        return permission;
    }

    // Convert string array to comma separated string
    private String getFeatures(FeatureInfo[] reqFeatures) {
        String features = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < reqFeatures.length; i++) {
            features = features + reqFeatures[i] + ",\n";
        }
        return features;
    }
}
```

AppData class

```
package com.example.appslist.app;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;

public class AppData extends Application {

    PackageInfo packageInfo;

    public PackageInfo getPackageInfo() {
        return packageInfo;
    }

    public void setPackageInfo(PackageInfo packageInfo) {
        this.packageInfo = packageInfo;
    }
}
```

I have tried registering AppData in manifest,tried using bundle, it force closes. Please help .

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.appslist"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    >

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.appslist.ApkListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ApkInfo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_apk_info" >
        </activity>
    </application>



</manifest>
```

Here is the LogCat

```
04-09 12:17:47.305: E/asset(5752): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.example.appslist === version 1
04-09 12:17:47.329: D/dalvikvm(5752): Trying to load lib lib_glossary.so 0x0
04-09 12:17:47.329: I/dalvikvm(5752): Unable to dlopen(lib_glossary.so): Cannot load library: load_library[1083]: Library 'lib_glossary.so' not found
04-09 12:17:47.329: E/MBGlossaryManager(5752): lib_glossary.so can't be loaded
04-09 12:17:47.469: E/asset(5752): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.google.android.location === version 8
04-09 12:17:47.469: E/asset(5752): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.launcher === version 8
04-09 12:17:47.477: E/asset(5752): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.defcontainer === version 8
04-09 12:17:47.477: E/asset(5752): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.navngo.igo.javaclient === version 148360
04-09 12:17:47.485: E/asset(5752): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.contacts === version 8
04-09 12:17:47.493: E/asset(5752): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.example.backgroundapp === version 1
04-09 12:17:47.493: E/asset(5752): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.arcsoft.photoworkshop === version 5
04-09 12:17:47.548: D/dalvikvm(5752): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 934 objects / 65512 bytes in 49ms
04-09 12:17:47.555: E/asset(5752): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.phone === version 8
04-09 12:17:47.563: E/asset(5752): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.calculator2 === version 8
04-09 12:17:47.563: E/asset(5752): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.htmlviewer === version 8
04-09 12:17:47.563: E/asset(5752): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.example.myfirstapp === version 1
04-09 12:17:47.571: E/asset(5752): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.providers.calendar === version 8
04-09 12:17:47.571: E/asset(5752): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.bluetooth === version 8
04-09 12:17:47.571: E/asset(5752): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.example.sessionmanagement === version 1
04-09 12:17:47.579: E/asset(5752): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.google.android.location === version 8
04-09 12:17:47.579: E/asset(5752): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.launcher === version 8
04-09 12:17:47.587: E/asset(5752): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.defcontainer === version 8
04-09 12:17:47.587: E/asset(5752): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.navngo.igo.javaclient === version 148360
04-09 12:17:47.594: E/asset(5752): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.contacts === version 8
04-09 12:17:47.641: E/asset(5752): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.example.backgroundapp === version 1
04-09 12:17:47.782: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(5752): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
04-09 12:17:47.782: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(5752): clearMetaKeyStates on inactive InputConnection
04-09 12:17:49.704: D/AndroidRuntime(5752): Shutting down VM
04-09 12:17:49.704: W/dalvikvm(5752): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207e0)
04-09 12:17:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5752): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 12:17:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5752): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
04-09 12:17:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5752):     at com.example.appslist.ApkListActivity.onItemClick(ApkListActivity.java:42)
04-09 12:17:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5752):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
04-09 12:17:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5752):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3444)
04-09 12:17:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5752):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
04-09 12:17:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5752):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-09 12:17:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5752):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-09 12:17:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5752):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
04-09 12:17:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5752):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4717)
04-09 12:17:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5752):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 12:17:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5752):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-09 12:17:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5752):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
04-09 12:17:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5752):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-09 12:17:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(5752):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-09 12:17:51.118: I/Process(5752): Sending signal. PID: 5752 SIG: 9
04-09 12:24:48.087: E/asset(5827): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.example.appslist === version 1
04-09 12:24:48.102: D/dalvikvm(5827): Trying to load lib lib_glossary.so 0x0
04-09 12:24:48.110: I/dalvikvm(5827): Unable to dlopen(lib_glossary.so): Cannot load library: load_library[1083]: Library 'lib_glossary.so' not found
04-09 12:24:48.110: E/MBGlossaryManager(5827): lib_glossary.so can't be loaded
04-09 12:24:48.212: E/asset(5827): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.google.android.location === version 8
04-09 12:24:48.219: E/asset(5827): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.launcher === version 8
04-09 12:24:48.219: E/asset(5827): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.defcontainer === version 8
04-09 12:24:48.219: E/asset(5827): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.navngo.igo.javaclient === version 148360
04-09 12:24:48.227: E/asset(5827): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.contacts === version 8
04-09 12:24:48.235: E/asset(5827): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.example.backgroundapp === version 1
04-09 12:24:48.235: E/asset(5827): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.arcsoft.photoworkshop === version 5
04-09 12:24:48.298: D/dalvikvm(5827): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 971 objects / 66752 bytes in 58ms
04-09 12:24:48.305: E/asset(5827): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.phone === version 8
04-09 12:24:48.313: E/asset(5827): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.calculator2 === version 8
04-09 12:24:48.313: E/asset(5827): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.htmlviewer === version 8
04-09 12:24:48.313: E/asset(5827): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.example.myfirstapp === version 1
04-09 12:24:48.321: E/asset(5827): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.providers.calendar === version 8
04-09 12:24:48.321: E/asset(5827): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.bluetooth === version 8
04-09 12:24:48.329: E/asset(5827): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.example.sessionmanagement === version 1
04-09 12:24:48.329: E/asset(5827): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.google.android.location === version 8
04-09 12:24:48.329: E/asset(5827): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.launcher === version 8
04-09 12:24:48.337: E/asset(5827): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.defcontainer === version 8
04-09 12:24:48.337: E/asset(5827): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.navngo.igo.javaclient === version 148360
04-09 12:24:48.344: E/asset(5827): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.contacts === version 8
04-09 12:24:48.391: E/asset(5827): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.example.backgroundapp === version 1
04-09 12:24:49.805: D/AndroidRuntime(5827): Shutting down VM
04-09 12:24:49.805: W/dalvikvm(5827): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207e0)
04-09 12:24:49.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5827): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 12:24:49.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5827): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
04-09 12:24:49.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at com.example.appslist.ApkListActivity.onItemClick(ApkListActivity.java:42)
04-09 12:24:49.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
04-09 12:24:49.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3444)
04-09 12:24:49.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
04-09 12:24:49.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-09 12:24:49.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-09 12:24:49.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
04-09 12:24:49.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4717)
04-09 12:24:49.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 12:24:49.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-09 12:24:49.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
04-09 12:24:49.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-09 12:24:49.821: E/AndroidRuntime(5827):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-09 12:24:51.688: I/Process(5827): Sending signal. PID: 5827 SIG: 9
04-09 12:24:55.165: E/asset(5835): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.example.appslist === version 1
04-09 12:24:55.188: D/dalvikvm(5835): Trying to load lib lib_glossary.so 0x0
04-09 12:24:55.188: I/dalvikvm(5835): Unable to dlopen(lib_glossary.so): Cannot load library: load_library[1083]: Library 'lib_glossary.so' not found
04-09 12:24:55.188: E/MBGlossaryManager(5835): lib_glossary.so can't be loaded
04-09 12:24:55.313: E/asset(5835): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.google.android.location === version 8
04-09 12:24:55.321: E/asset(5835): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.launcher === version 8
04-09 12:24:55.329: E/asset(5835): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.defcontainer === version 8
04-09 12:24:55.329: E/asset(5835): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.navngo.igo.javaclient === version 148360
04-09 12:24:55.337: E/asset(5835): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.contacts === version 8
04-09 12:24:55.337: E/asset(5835): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.example.backgroundapp === version 1
04-09 12:24:55.344: E/asset(5835): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.arcsoft.photoworkshop === version 5
04-09 12:24:55.391: D/dalvikvm(5835): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 993 objects / 67608 bytes in 49ms
04-09 12:24:55.407: E/asset(5835): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.phone === version 8
04-09 12:24:55.415: E/asset(5835): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.calculator2 === version 8
04-09 12:24:55.415: E/asset(5835): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.htmlviewer === version 8
04-09 12:24:55.415: E/asset(5835): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.example.myfirstapp === version 1
04-09 12:24:55.423: E/asset(5835): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.providers.calendar === version 8
04-09 12:24:55.423: E/asset(5835): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.bluetooth === version 8
04-09 12:24:55.423: E/asset(5835): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.example.sessionmanagement === version 1
04-09 12:24:55.430: E/asset(5835): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.google.android.location === version 8
04-09 12:24:55.430: E/asset(5835): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.launcher === version 8
04-09 12:24:55.438: E/asset(5835): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.defcontainer === version 8
04-09 12:24:55.438: E/asset(5835): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.navngo.igo.javaclient === version 148360
04-09 12:24:55.446: E/asset(5835): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.contacts === version 8
04-09 12:24:55.493: E/asset(5835): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.example.backgroundapp === version 1
04-09 12:24:56.641: D/AndroidRuntime(5835): Shutting down VM
04-09 12:24:56.641: W/dalvikvm(5835): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207e0)
04-09 12:24:56.657: E/AndroidRuntime(5835): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 12:24:56.657: E/AndroidRuntime(5835): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
04-09 12:24:56.657: E/AndroidRuntime(5835):     at com.example.appslist.ApkListActivity.onItemClick(ApkListActivity.java:42)
04-09 12:24:56.657: E/AndroidRuntime(5835):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
04-09 12:24:56.657: E/AndroidRuntime(5835):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3444)
04-09 12:24:56.657: E/AndroidRuntime(5835):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
04-09 12:24:56.657: E/AndroidRuntime(5835):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-09 12:24:56.657: E/AndroidRuntime(5835):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-09 12:24:56.657: E/AndroidRuntime(5835):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
04-09 12:24:56.657: E/AndroidRuntime(5835):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4717)
04-09 12:24:56.657: E/AndroidRuntime(5835):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 12:24:56.657: E/AndroidRuntime(5835):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-09 12:24:56.657: E/AndroidRuntime(5835):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
04-09 12:24:56.657: E/AndroidRuntime(5835):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-09 12:24:56.657: E/AndroidRuntime(5835):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-09 12:24:58.040: I/Process(5835): Sending signal. PID: 5835 SIG: 9
04-09 12:39:54.556: I/Process(5930): Sending signal. PID: 5930 SIG: 9
04-09 12:43:51.244: E/asset(5972): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.example.appslist === version 1
04-09 12:43:51.283: D/dalvikvm(5972): Trying to load lib lib_glossary.so 0x0
04-09 12:43:51.291: I/dalvikvm(5972): Unable to dlopen(lib_glossary.so): Cannot load library: load_library[1083]: Library 'lib_glossary.so' not found
04-09 12:43:51.291: E/MBGlossaryManager(5972): lib_glossary.so can't be loaded
04-09 12:43:51.494: E/asset(5972): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.google.android.location === version 8
04-09 12:43:51.494: E/asset(5972): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.launcher === version 8
04-09 12:43:51.502: E/asset(5972): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.defcontainer === version 8
04-09 12:43:51.509: E/asset(5972): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.navngo.igo.javaclient === version 148360
04-09 12:43:51.509: E/asset(5972): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.contacts === version 8
04-09 12:43:51.517: E/asset(5972): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.example.backgroundapp === version 1
04-09 12:43:51.517: E/asset(5972): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.arcsoft.photoworkshop === version 5
04-09 12:43:51.580: D/dalvikvm(5972): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1059 objects / 70176 bytes in 57ms
04-09 12:43:51.588: E/asset(5972): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.phone === version 8
04-09 12:43:51.595: E/asset(5972): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.calculator2 === version 8
04-09 12:43:51.595: E/asset(5972): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.htmlviewer === version 8
04-09 12:43:51.595: E/asset(5972): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.example.myfirstapp === version 1
04-09 12:43:51.603: E/asset(5972): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.providers.calendar === version 8
04-09 12:43:51.603: E/asset(5972): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.bluetooth === version 8
04-09 12:43:51.611: E/asset(5972): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.example.sessionmanagement === version 1
04-09 12:43:51.611: E/asset(5972): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.google.android.location === version 8
04-09 12:43:51.619: E/asset(5972): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.launcher === version 8
04-09 12:43:51.619: E/asset(5972): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.defcontainer === version 8
04-09 12:43:51.619: E/asset(5972): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.navngo.igo.javaclient === version 148360
04-09 12:43:51.627: E/asset(5972): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.android.contacts === version 8
04-09 12:43:51.673: E/asset(5972): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: com.example.backgroundapp === version 1
04-09 12:43:56.166: D/AndroidRuntime(5972): Shutting down VM
04-09 12:43:56.166: W/dalvikvm(5972): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207e0)
04-09 12:43:56.189: E/AndroidRuntime(5972): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 12:43:56.189: E/AndroidRuntime(5972): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
04-09 12:43:56.189: E/AndroidRuntime(5972):     at com.example.appslist.ApkListActivity.onItemClick(ApkListActivity.java:43)
04-09 12:43:56.189: E/AndroidRuntime(5972):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
04-09 12:43:56.189: E/AndroidRuntime(5972):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3444)
04-09 12:43:56.189: E/AndroidRuntime(5972):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
04-09 12:43:56.189: E/AndroidRuntime(5972):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-09 12:43:56.189: E/AndroidRuntime(5972):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-09 12:43:56.189: E/AndroidRuntime(5972):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
04-09 12:43:56.189: E/AndroidRuntime(5972):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4717)
04-09 12:43:56.189: E/AndroidRuntime(5972):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 12:43:56.189: E/AndroidRuntime(5972):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-09 12:43:56.189: E/AndroidRuntime(5972):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
04-09 12:43:56.189: E/AndroidRuntime(5972):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-09 12:43:56.189: E/AndroidRuntime(5972):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-09 12:43:57.486: I/Process(5972): Sending signal. PID: 5972 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you extend application class, you should modify you manifest [add android:name]. In your case, you should add to manifest:

```
 <application
        android:name=".app.AppData"
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, It worked . I had added it earlier but syntax was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the error log carefully, you'll see what your problem is.  It's on line

```
AppData appData = (AppData) getApplication();
```

of your `onItemClick` method.  `getApplication` method returns `com.android.Application`, which you are trying to cast to `AppData` class, however it is not an instance of `AppData`.

While every instance of `AppData` is also an instance of `Application`, the same is not true the other way around: an instance of `Application` is not automatically an instance of its subclass.

Comment: Can you please suggest what changes I should make, I am new to android programming ansstuck up with this since a long time :(

Comment: @Prax I can't suggest any changes, at the least because I don't know what you're trying to do.  As you are new, I suggest you use all available resources.  Almost every possible question has been asked and answered before.  Search google, review API specifications and examples, search this site.  And don't try it just once.  Change search criteria, etc.  If you really try, you'll find the answers.

Comment: Oh,No problem, It worked now there was error in Manifest, I was trying it since a week. Thanks any way for your time and help, and next time I have a problem, I will keep your words in mind . THanks :)